# Installing jvm files using Yocto

Tags: java, jvm, yocto, openembedded

Trying to install JVM files into rootfs but seeing following errors:

```
--> Starting dependency resolution
--> Finished dependency resolution
Error: 
Problem: conflicting requests
- nothing provides libgif.so.7()(64bit) needed by jvm-1.0-r0.aarch64
- nothing provides libjpeg.so.62()(64bit) needed by jvm-1.0-r0.aarch64
- nothing provides libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) needed by jvm-1.0-r0.aarch64
 (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best c 
 candidate packages) 
 ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: 
 ERROR: core-image-minimal-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
```

Its just custom recipe file jvm.bb which compiled well but while installing into rootfs seeing about issue.

Is there a workaround for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Are you tried to skip file deps to jvm recipe

```
SKIP_FILEDEPS:${PN} = '1'
```